# htaccess redirect from url parameter to permalink

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect urls like:
https://www.example.com/blog/en/xyz
to: 
https://www.example.com/en-blog.php?article=xyz

using htaccess. How is that possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the artivle slug from the query string using a `RewriteCond`, since you cannot access it in a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)?article=(.*)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?en-blog\.php$ /blog/en/%1 [R]
```

That rule should work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! Though I accidentally swapped the redirect. Could you please check the edited question? I tried: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)?article=(.*)(&|$)
RewriteRule /blog/en/%1 ^/?en-blog\.php$  [R]                                               
but it doesn't work

Comment: Hm, I actually doubt you want to do that... Could it be that you also confused the terms "redirect" and "rewrite"? Maybe you should invest a few minutes to actually explain in your question what you want to do instead of trying to tell us how you think you might be able to do that...